# How do you search a column that uses a select element to search on its value instead of its key with datatables.net in js

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, datatables, combobox

So I have a table column that uses a list of key value pairs in a razor page for a select element and when searching the table using the main datatables search bar this column gets searched on the id and not the value when using said datatables search bar. How can I allow he regular search on the other columns and do a custom search on this 1 column based on its value instead of the id while still using only the main search bar?

Here is the column creation in the razor using a html input datatable creator method:

```
new Column("PositionID", ColumnType.Enum, width: "20%", values: Model.Positions, required: true, label: "Craft", dataAttribute: "id=\"PositionID\"", className: "select2Class", readOnly: false);
```

And the closest js function event that i have gotten to work is this but it doesnt get hit with every keyup event on the search bar so im not sure its reliable for this although i believe it would potentially work otherwise.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {
    
       debugger;
       return true;
 });
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Rostami, could you pls share enough code to reproduce your issue and it also help members understand your requirement more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you have tried but I would use the columns.render property. See

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

In particular when the render type is 'filter'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, without changing the table creation im not sure I can utilize this method. I added some code to the post and it almost seems to work but it doesnt seem to get hit if the values dont already match the search criteria, almost as if its anextra  post search filter.